# Can't center vertically multiple(all) td of a table(Responsive)

Tags: html, css

I am unable to center vertically all td of the table.

It looks okay(vertically centered) in 600px but in mobile devices(max-width:550px) all td of the table is not vertically centering.

I want all text to be vertically centered. How to do this? Don't use float, position:relative/absolute because I am trying to make a html newsletter that doesn't support float/position:relative/absolute.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:550px) {
  .hp {width:100%!important; height:auto!important;}
  .mob-column {float:none!important; width:100%!important; display:block!important;}
}
```

```html
<table width="600" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="33.33%" height="192" class="mob-column" align="left"
            style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;"
            bgcolor="#000080">

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" width="33.33%" align="left" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;" class="mob-column">
                    <v:fill type="cover" src="images/chicken-food.jpg" color="#000080"/>
                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->

            <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff;">
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">Chicken Food</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:10.29px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">From</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">$10.99</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->

        </td>
        <td width="33.33%" height="192" class="mob-column" align="left"
            style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;"
            bgcolor="#000080">

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" width="33.33%" align="left" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;" class="mob-column">
                    <v:fill type="cover" src="images/pizza-specials.jpg" color="#000080"/>
                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->

            <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff;">
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">Pizza Specials</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-size:10.29px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">From</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">$10.99</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->

        </td>
        <td width="33.33%" height="192" class="mob-column" align="left"
            style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;"
            bgcolor="#000080">

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" width="33.33%" align="left" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:33.33%; height:192px; background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/200X192.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 100%;" class="mob-column">
                    <v:fill type="cover" src="images/precious-wine.jpg" color="#000080"/>
                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:true;" inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->

            <table width="100%" class="hp" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff;">
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 32px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:15.43px; text-transform:uppercase; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">Precious Wine</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="color:#cac8c6; font-family:'Montserrat', Arial; font-size:10.29px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">From</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style="padding:0px 20px 0px 20px; font-family:'Roboto', Arial; font-weight:900; font-size:25.89px; line-height:150%; word-spacing:0px; letter-spacing:0px;">
                        <span class="fallback-text">$10.99</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->

        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if you want it to work then you should remove inline style, all elements have inline-style in your HTML, I think this is the cause that its not working.

Comment: @ROOT, Can you give a working example with the code?